# why do the regex expression /d/.test() return true? test function with no arguments

Tags: javascript, regex

I test on my chrome dev console and find that /d/.test() return true. That confuse me.Is there any special meaning for the 'd'?

Comment: It’s testing `"undefined"`.

Comment: Thanks,that help me a lot .

Answer (score 3):

There is no special meaning to `d` but when you don't pass any parameters to `.test`, this results in `undefined` being compared. When turned into a string, this produces `"undefined"` and then `d` matches the letter there.

```js
console.log(/u/.test());
console.log(/n/.test());
console.log(/d/.test());
console.log(/e/.test());
console.log(/f/.test());
console.log(/i/.test());

console.log(/undefined/.test());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: inherit !important;
}
```